# Spring test @Sql not inserting data from sql file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a spring boot project and I am writing tests for it. I am using a h2 database. My ApplicationTests has these annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Sql( scripts = { "classpath:db/data.sql" }, config = @SqlConfig(transactionMode = SqlConfig.TransactionMode.ISOLATED))
@ActiveProfiles("test")
```

I know that the data in data.sql is inserted because if I put an incorrect sql statement in it I get an error when starting the tests so data.sql is run on the h2 database. My data.sql looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO language VALUES (1, 'English');
```

When my first test starts I count the records in the language table and there are none. Either the data in data.sql is not being commited or somewhere spring is doing a rollback meaning the data is not in the h2 database anymore and not accessible during tests. Does anybody have a clue what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are writing to h2 database ?

How have you defined your datasource bean in your application. 
Eg.. If you are using mysql db for your  application but for testing you using h2 database, and if you don't mention explicitly to your test class to use h2 database, it may use your mysql db which you defined for your application)

May be you can try below code, which  will not replace your h2 database which you are using for testing.

```
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)
```

Comment: Unfornataly that didn't work. What I have done is override the spring.datasource.url property and I can see that when the tests start and the application starts that the h2 connection string is used. I noticed something. 

I am using flyway and I see that when the application starts that the sql files are run on the h2 database however when the Dao tests starts the flyway sql files are run again and without error. It would seem as if the h2 database is either emptied or the flayway sql files initializy isn't saved into the database.

Comment: Going through my logs I found out what's causing this. I saw DROP TABLE lines in my console and it appears that spring/hibernate is dropping the tables. I see the line Running hbm2ddl schema export and then alot of drop statements. 

I have tried to disable hbm2ddl however nothing seems to work. So if you having this problem it has to do with spring or Hibernate thinking that it's smart to set the default option to dropping of the database structure.